# Fragment shows up on my phone but not in XML preview

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an activity `LoginActivity` and a fragment `GoogleSignInFragment`. The login logic for the app works perfectly okay but the only thing bugging me is the fact that the `GoogleSignInFragment` didn't show up in the XML preview for `activity_login.xml`. Without it showing up, it'll be very difficult for me to move my code to Fragments, since I can't style the activity as well anymore

Here's all the relevant code...

`LoginActivity.java`

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.sign_in_google, new GoogleSignInFragment())
                .commit();

}
```

`activity_login.xml`

```xml
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_google"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sign_in_google_button"/>
```

`GoogleSignInFragment.java`

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_google_sign_in_button, container, false);

    return v;
}
```

`fragment_google_sign_in_button.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    tools:context=".GoogleSignInFragment">

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_google_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolslayout

Says it's meant for intended for: `<fragment>` but you are using a `FrameLayout`

Comment: But it asks me to use `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` instead which doesn't work. Should I just ignore the recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Android Studio fails to load preview so you can try **Invalidate Cache / Restart** option in **File** option.

For this, Go to **File** > Click on **Invalidate Cache / Restart**

Answer (score 0):

I think they're no problem with your code ad your fragment *activity_login.xml* does not contain anything and *fragment_google_sign_in_button.xml* contains *com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton* is used with help of an external library so sometimes preview not shows.

Comment: But I just made another new fragment with just a TextView and this issue still showed up

Comment: Then Clean your project and Rebuild it may be this will solve your problem

Comment: please don't refer to people as `Bro`, it can be seen as disrepectful and really doesn't add any value to your answer